# Laravel uploading multiple files in different fields in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying three images in three different fields in database..for that I was following method in controller.But the problem I'm facing is though i have three input fields it stored only two images **with same name** in the public folder and in database it stored value like `1 (for product_image), 4 ( for vendor_image), 9 (for user_image)`.
How do i properly stored the images in public folder as well as database..thanks in advance .

Here is the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $product = new Product();
    $files= [];

    if($request->file('product_image'))   $files[] = $request->file('product_image');
    if($request->file('vendor_image'))   $files[] = $request->file('vendor_image');
    if($request->file('user_image'))     $files[] = $request->file('user_image');


      foreach($files as $file)
      {    
          if(!empty($file))
          {
              $filename = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
              $file->move('images/',$filename);
          }
      }
      $product->product_image = $filename[0];
        
      $product->vendor_image = $filename[1];

      $product->user_image = $filename[2];
      $product->save();
  }
```

here is the View part :

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Product Image</label>
     <input type="file" name="product_image"  id="product_image" width="200px">                                              
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Feature Image</label>
     <input type="file" name="vendor_image"  id="vendor_image" width="200px">
                                        
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Slurp Image</label>
     <input type="file" name="user_image"  id="user_image" width="200px">                                          
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function imageupload(Request $request) {
        $files=[];
        if($request->file('profilePhoto')) $files[]=$request->file('profilePhoto');
        if($request->file('fssaiPhoto')) $files[]=$request->file('fssaiPhoto');
        if($request->file('panPhoto')) $files[]=$request->file('panPhoto');

        foreach($files as $file){
                $uniqid = Str::random(9);
        $fileName = $uniqid.'.'.$file->extension();  
     
        $file->move(public_path('file'), $fileName);
        
        $data[]=$fileName;
            
        } 
            $images=new fileuploadmodels;
            $images->phno=$request->phno;
            $images->profilePhoto=$data[0];
            $images->fssaiPhoto=$data[1];
            $images->panPhoto=$data[2];
            $images->save();
            return response()->json([
                "message"=>"photo upload success"
            ],201);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$product_image = NULL;
$vendor_image= NULL;
$user_image= NULL;
if($request->product_image)
{
     $product_image= time().'-'. $request->product_image->getClientOriginalName();
     $request->product_image->move(public_path('images/'),$product_image);
}
if($request->vendor_image)
{
     $vendor_image= time().'-'. $request->vendor_image->getClientOriginalName();
     $request->vendor_image->move(public_path('images/'),$vendor_image);
}
if($request->user_image)
{
     $user_image= time().'-'. $request->user_image->getClientOriginalName();
     $request->user_image->move(public_path('images/'),$user_image);
}

$product->product_image = $product_image;
        
$product->vendor_image = $vendor_image;

$product->user_image = $user_image;
$product->save();
```